# Contribution - Wrong VAT amount showing

Tags: contributions, taxes

We collect a number of monthly direct debit payments of £30 using SmartDebit. The breakdown is £25 fee + £5 VAT.

Although the SmartDebit report shows that we collected £30, in civi (under contributions) the total amount is showing as £36 (£30 + £6 VAT).

Is there a way of changing this so that the correct amounts appear. I am using civi 5.10.3 and SmartDebit version 1.30

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user6930, Welcome to SE world.

Unfortunately this is a know issue in CiviCRM when subsequent recurring payment is recorded in CiviCRM which has tax. It would be good if you add some resource so that it gets fixed in core.

Alternate method is to turn off sales tax or do a contribution(batch) update to update the amount from $36 to 30

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thank you, Pradeep. I though this may be the case.