# Invoice for membership with auto-renewal wrong - VAT added twice

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, stripe, invoice, taxes

After I configured a membership with the option of auto-renewal (recurring contribution) the generated invoices seem to be wrong. The amount for the membership payment line item is not stated as net, but already includes VAT. In addition, VAT is listed in the invoice and added on top of the gross amount. The processed transaction in the backend (Stripe in this case) is correct in terms of charges (regular gross amount, no double VAT).

The invoice was correct without activating the auto-renewal option.

CiviCRM is version 5.16.2 on WordPress 5.2.3 with Stripe payment extension 5.4.1

I found the following Q&A on StackExchange:
[Contribution - Wrong VAT amount showing](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/29000/contribution-wrong-vat-amount-showing)

The above question was "just" related to a wrong report. In this case, the issue seems more serious. At least according to German tax law, if the VAT amount in an issued invoice is accidentally stated too high, the issuer of the invoice owes the full stated VAT amount to the fiscal authorities.

I was trying to have a look at the open issues list, but was not able to find the (known?) issue.

My questions are:

- Are other users seeing the same behavior?
- Is this potential bug already known?
- Is there a known workaround?

Many Thanks!